# General Statement for SecureRandom return Error - Java

Tags: java, cryptography, sunspot

I've searched throughout different forums and now I am finally putting my question as I can't find specific answer.

I am writing security protocol for SunSPOT Sensors as my final year Project.

I wish to generate a 128 bit Key which can be hashed later on, through my search on web I come across that best method to generate the random keys is SecureRandom.

I am trying to implement the general statement to see how it works so that I can use it further according to my requirement

```
SecureRandom gen = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1WITHECDSA");
```

above statment I have used with "SHA1PRNG", "MD5ECDSA" and "ECDSAWithSHA1Signature" 
as soon as I complete Statement and put semicolon it return this Error

> method getInstance in class
>   com.sun.spot.security.implementation.SecureRandom
>   cannot be applied to given types
>   required: byte found: java.lang.String

I have added the Jar file respectively to the build.xml and into the build.properties ; also the imported the algorithm into the program.

Thanks for reading

and any help is much appriciated

Thankyou Every One  who have tried to help.

Hash (Hasnain)

Comment: Please copy and paste the entire stack trace.

Comment: @GregS : I beg your pardon, Stack Trace ? what do you require to help.

Comment: Stack traces happen with runtime failures. His code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Jorn, thanks, I mistakenly thought he was seeing a runtime exception.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just say "SecureRandom()" and let the system pick the algorithm? Here is an explicit example:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Rando {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new SecureRandom().nextFloat());
    }

}
```

Comment: I am sorry I think I just ammended your reply to comment on it

Comment: General Defination return the error such as "cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method SecureRandom() "

Comment: I added an example of exactly how to do this.

Comment: "http://www.sunspotworld.com/docs/Red/hostjavadoc/com/sun/squawk/security/signing/package-summary.html" also the Demo code is attached "http://www.4shared.com/dir/tJvfDOwg/Code.html" check the line 53 for the getinstance algorithm; further the Jar file is attached so you can verify that I can use SecureRandom.

Comment: I can't use the same class as Java.security.SecureRandom as it is for J2SE, I am working on special build JVM called Squawk ... am I able to build the same information ??? few documantation and relavent information which I know is attached for your information. kindly advice further

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the correct class? You should be using [java.security.SecureRandom](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html). Also, `SHA1WITHECDSA`, `MD5ECDSA`, and `ECDSAWithSHA1Signature` are nonsensical as SecureRandom instances.

Comment: @ Greg S : Thanks for your response I am writing code for SunSPOT sensor (sunspotworld.com) and the location of Secure Random class for squawk based device is "com.sun.spot.security.implementation.SecureRandom". Please guide me with a different suggestion. Thank you

Comment: ahh, sorry, I was not familiar with sun spot. I went on to sunspotworld.com website, took a look at the APIs and found no SecureRandom class of any kind. Can you provide a link to the javadocs for that class?

Comment: Thanks Greg S for showing intrest .... "http://www.sunspotworld.com/docs/Red/hostjavadoc/com/sun/squawk/security/signing/package-summary.html" also the Demo code is attached "http://www.4shared.com/dir/tJvfDOwg/Code.html" check the line 53 for the getinstance algorithm; further the Jar file is attached so you can verify that I can use SecureRandom

Comment: The [page](http://www.sunspotworld.com/docs/Red/hostjavadoc/com/sun/squawk/security/signing/package-summary.html) you link to does not have a SecureRandom class. The code of your link shows Signature.getInstance, not SecureRandom.getInstance.

Comment: yes true but SHA algorithm is the same for using as a Signature or SecureRandom. Plus the class has SecureRandom not the Javadoc (Check Jar for SecureRandom). therefore I am asking the question on forum about this problem, if I had documentation I might have tried to read through it earlier

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me as if you're calling a method that requires a `byte` as argument, but you are supplying a `String`.

Comment: Yes that's the error ... But Although If you "put SecureRandom gen = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"); which is the general statement it will return the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

The error is referring to the class `com.sun.spot.security.implementation.SecureRandom`.  You should presumably be using `java.security.SecureRandom` (it is this class that has the `getInstance` method that takes a String).

You probably have an incorrect import statement.

Comment: @ Dan Dyer : Thanks for your response I am writing code for SunSPOT sensor (http://www.sunspotworld.com/) and the location of Secure Random class for squawk based device is correct as I mentioned. Please refer me to a different suggestion. Thank You

Comment: @Hash The Sunspot SecureRandom class is not the same as `java.security.SecureRandom` (I didn't realise that this was not included in the Sunspot API).  It's not the same class in a different package, it's a different class with the same name.  You can't call `getInstance(String)` on it because it doesn't have that method.  The example code you are copying probably expects `java.security.SecureRandom`.  The Sunspot class does have a method `getInstance(byte)`, you should probably investigate that.

Comment: Thanks Greg S for showing intrest .... "http://www.sunspotworld.com/docs/Red/hostjavadoc/com/sun/squawk/security/signing/package-summary.html" also the Demo code is attached "http://www.4shared.com/dir/tJvfDOwg/Code.html" check the line 53 for the getinstance algorithm; further the Jar file is attached so you can verify that I can use SecureRandom

Answer (score 0):

Instance required for secure random in SunSPOT java application is as follow

> SecureRandom gen;
>        gen = SecureRandom.getInstance(SecureRandom.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);

I would like to Thank Everyone who put their effort to resolve this error.

Thanks once again.